KSQLDB Deserialization error - Schema not found; error code: 40403
create stream test_s1 (
    "after" struct<
        "up" varchar,
        "u" varchar,
        "num" varchar
    >,
    "op" varchar
)
with (kafka_topic='test_raw_v1',
    VALUE_AVRO_SCHEMA_FULL_NAME='com.xyz.IdEvent', value_format='AVRO');

Hello Everyone,
I created stream "test_s1" using above query, which is backed by an existing topic "test_raw_v1". This Topic has schema registered in the schema registry under namespace "com.xyz.IdEvent" with AVRO value format.
This Topic is regularly getting events. I only have access to the kafka UI and can execute KSQL queries to debug. When I ran "DESCRIBE" on above stream, it is showing all messages failed in the error stats. After that I checked KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG and found below deserialization errors with "Schema not found..." message. However when I checked, the schema version id 100540 of schema associated with topic "test_raw_v1" does exist. Can someone tell what could be the reason?
{ "TYPE": 0, "DESERIALIZATIONERROR": { "TARGET": "value", "ERRORMESSAGE": "Error deserializing message from topic: test_raw_v1", "RECORDB64": <Removed Base64 encoded message for security> , "CAUSE": [ "Failed to deserialize data for topic test_raw_v1 to Avro: ", "Error retrieving Avro value schema version for id 100540", "Schema not found; error code: 40403" ], "topic": "test_raw_v1" }, "RECORDPROCESSINGERROR": null, "PRODUCTIONERROR": null, "SERIALIZATIONERROR": null, "KAFKASTREAMSTHREADERROR": null

